# Bootstrap 3 uneven header color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I didn't really know how to put it in words so here is what i actually need to create but have no idea how.

I'm using the latest version of bootstrap

This is the desired effect
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwq39tbswp44j1i/desired.jpg?dl=0

and this is what I currently have

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksvgf9ohdmln6xe/Screenshot%202015-05-03%2002.01.19.png?dl=0

this is the markup

```html
<div class="container">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png">
   <h1>The text</h1>
</div>
```

so what would you recommned the site has to be responsive and in terms of mobile version i think the best case sceneario would either be smaller font or stack it on top of each other.

Please help me I'm quite desperate.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is

Comment: Desperate and very unclear. Make a jsfiddle and edit your question so we actually know what your asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't completely clear what you are asking for, but I'll give it a try.

The first issue that I see is the that you aren't following proper bootstrap layout rules (see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).  Below is an example of how to do it.  To keep items lined up horizontally, you need to have `<div class='row'>`.  Below is what I think you are looking for.

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-xs-3'>
            <img class="img-responsive"  src="http://www.xamalot.com/preview/png3/5e78c8d8-3f02-4e3c-9a3a-d95432c606e3" /> 
         </div>
         <div class='col-xs-9'>
            <h1>The text</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I have put together a working sample at http://jsbin.com/mafuxeyebu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I forgot to add to boostrap markup but that's not imporant. The thing I wanted was this: header is divided into two uneven secton both of which have it's own background

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but you could try using a screenshot program to capture the desired header as an image then you would not have to build it.

To make an image responsive in bootstrap you can just use the responsive class:

```
<img class="responsive">
```

I just used awesome-screenshot to grab that as an image

[image]
right click> open image in new tab if you just want to use this image

Now You could use GIMP or Photoshop to edit in your logo/ slogan.

Obviously this is a work around, but then again im not even sure this is what you wanted.

Thanks